# Is it possible to read .mq files from MSMQ storage directly?

Tags: msmq

So we recently got this dreaded MSMQ error on one of our servers after a restart:

> The Message Queuing service cannot start because a queue is in an
>   inconsistent state. For more information, see Microsoft Knowledge Base
>   article 827493 at support.microsoft.com.

This indicates that there is some corruption with the storage files (*.mq) in the configured storage location.

Other than completely removing all *.mq files to get MSMQ running again, I have been unable to find any other solution that can recover any data directly from those files. Even copying the .mq files back in doesn't work so I am looking for an alternative.

As far as my understanding goes, MSMQ uses Memory-Mapped files to store message data. There is an 8kb index file l*.mq and a matching 4MB data file p*.mq.

I haven't been able to find out any more info on how these files are structured but what I want to know is if there is a way to interpret the index files so that the data files can be read and I can recover the message data?

My first attempt at doing this didn't work out very well. I assumed that since the index file is only 8kb, then each byte must reference a 512 byte block in the data file (since it is 4MB). That doesn't seem to be the case...

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the total volume of *.MQ files?

Comment: I have 668 pairs of l*.mq and p*.mq files

Comment: " Even copying the .mq files back in doesn't work so I am looking for an alternative."
Was that all in one go? Have you tried restarting MSMQ with just one of the MQ pairs in the storage folder?

Comment: I tried copying in a few pairs and the first two seemed to work and then the third caused MSMQ to break again with the same error. I then tried a couple of other random pairs and ended up breaking MSMQ again. I guess I am looking for an alternate way to know which of the pairs are corrupt as it is a very cumbersome process having to stop MSMQ, copy in a .mq pair, start MSMQ and see if it breaks or not before moving on to the next pair.

Comment: I agree, it's a dreadful approach to have to use. Could be something to script overnight, maybe (copy files, start service, log if succeeds/fails, stop service, remove files, repeat).

Comment: The structure of the files isn't documented publicly, as far as I know. The index files should map to the data files as you suggest. They indicate whether a block is in use or free to write a message to. The old message data is not scrubbed, just like on a hard drive - it's just marked as free to overwrite when the message has been removed from the queue. If you open a data file in Notepad, you'll therefore see deleted messages (or parts of) as well as complete current ones.